# Adding text between figure number and its punctuations

Tags: captions

We are using the below definition to get the figure numberings automatically

```
\renewcommand\thefigure{\@arabic\c@figure}
\def\fnum@figure{\figurename~\thefigure}
```

The output is as shown below:

> Figure 1. Caption

But, we need to insert the text "(Online color)" after figure number as shown below:

> Figure 1 (Online color). Caption

To achieve this I again redefining the command

```
\def\fnum@figure{\figurename~\thefigure (Online color)}
```

which again I have to reset for the next captions.

Could anyone suggest how to get this automatically?

Comment: If you redefine `\fnum@figure` it will stay redefined unless something else changes it.  What class/packages are you using?  Can you please provide [an example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

This should get you started. I have defined a new environment `myfigure`. If you want

```
Figure 1 (Online color). Caption
```

use `myfigure` or else use `figure`.

A sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{#1 (Online color)#2#3}
\newenvironment{myfigure}%
{\captionsetup{format=myformat,labelsep=period}
\figure
}%
{\endfigure}%
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
  \begin{myfigure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption[myfig1]{my caption here}
  \end{myfigure}

  \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption[myfig2]{my caption here}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Further adjustments are left as assignment. For details refer to `caption` manual.

Answer (score 4):

Here a different solution with no need for additional packages.

Simply issue the command `\onlinecap` *inside* those `figure` environments where you want the modified caption.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thefigure{\@arabic\c@figure}
\renewcommand\fnum@figure{\figurename~\thefigure}
\newcommand\onlinecap{\renewcommand\fnum@figure{\figurename~\thefigure~(Online color)}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \caption{A}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \onlinecap
  \caption{B}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \caption{C}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Just in case you have `figure`s with multiple captions, you might need a command to nullify the effect of `\onlinecap` for a subsequent caption. In this case you might also insert between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` another line which defines a command `\offlinecap` for this purpose:

```
\newcommand\offlinecap{\renewcommand\fnum@figure{\figurename~\thefigure}}
```

Comment: Probably also an `\offlinecap` command should be provided, in case a `figure` environment has two captions, only the first of which has the addition.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the suggestion. Added in the answer.